# How to remove/reduce default spacing between table rows in fo:table while generating PDF

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I would like to reduce the line space between the rows in a fo:table. I tried using top, bottom on each row and space-before and space-after on fo:block and had no effect.

```html
<xsl:template match="region1">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" >
  <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
   <fo:table-column column-width="100%"/>
   <!-- <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>  -->
   <fo:table-body>
    <fo:table-row><fo:table-cell><fo:block font-family="Courier" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" white-space="pre" font-size="12pt"><xsl:value-of select="lines[1]/line"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row><fo:table-cell><fo:block font-family="Courier" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" white-space="pre" font-size="12pt"><xsl:value-of select="lines[2]/line"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row><fo:table-cell><fo:block font-family="Courier" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" white-space="pre" font-size="12pt"><xsl:value-of select="lines[3]/line"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row><fo:table-cell><fo:block font-family="Courier" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" white-space="pre" font-size="12pt"><xsl:value-of select="lines[4]/line"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row><fo:table-cell><fo:block font-family="Courier" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" white-space="pre" font-size="12pt"><xsl:value-of select="lines[5]/line"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row>
   </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
    </fo:static-content>
</xsl:template>
```

WHat I am getting is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2HLc.png)

What is expected is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2YZH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default line height which is the leading is probably 1.2 times the font size. Set line-height more appropriate to your case like maybe even line-height=0

Comment: Thanks for the info. This helped. I set the line-height 2pt less than the font size. Seems to be working Madhu

Comment: I am sorry, I am not seeing any link or button to say I accept. I clicked on the check link. I hope this is the way to accept.

Comment: It is. Welcome to Stackoverflow!